# How are security group rules evaluated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-networking

I am currently working my way through the **AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate (SAA-C02)** Linkedin Learning course and I came across something confusing regarding security groups.
During the lecture, the lecturer says that when using security groups:

> We evaluate all rules before deciding whether to allow traffic

As opposed to how NACLs work, where you stop processing once a rule matches.

But at the end of the lecture, the summary says the following:

> It is important to get the order of rules correct or the desired permissions will not be accomplished

I don't understand this. If all rules are evaluated, then why would their order matter? Furthermore, security groups only support allow rules. There is no case of one rule allowing traffic and another one denying it.

Comment: Their order matters only for NACLs, not for SGs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be multiple Security Groups on a resource. When evaluating Security Groups, **access is permitted if *any* security group rule permits access**. If no Security Group rule permits access, then access is Denied.

There is only one Network Access Control List (NACL) on a subnet. When evaluating a NACL, the rules are evaluated in order. There is a default rule that is **evaluated last**, which determines whether the default is Allow or Deny.

I agree with you that **the lecturer's statement appears inaccurate**.

Comment: It's also possible the lecturer was referring to NACLs in the summary. Hard to conclude without listening to the lecture. But as it stands @John is right. The statement is inaccurate.

Comment: Regarding Security Groups, if access is permitted if any security group rule permits access, why does it have to evaluate all rules? I imagine it would be more efficient to stop evaluating once a rule that allows is found?